# active_model_serializers association as:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm using ActiveModel::Serializer in my rails-api app. 
I have a polymorphic association called addonable:

```
class AddOn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addonable, polymorphic: true
end
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :add_ons, as: :addonable
end
class Depot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :add_ons, as: :addonable
end
```

Then, I have two different controllers, each of them returns a different addonable (Container or Depot). 
I would like the serializer to return the addonable association with its class name:

```
class DepotSelectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :quantity

  belongs_to :addonable,  serializer: DepotSerializer, polymorphic: true
end
#returns: {:data=>{:id=>:string, :type=>:string, :attributes=>{:quantity=>:integer}, :relationships=>{:addonable=>{:data=>:object}}}}

#I want: {:data=>{:id=>:string, :type=>:string, :attributes=>{:quantity=>:integer}, :relationships=>{:depot=>{:data=>:object}}}}
```

I want the object to be in the relationships hash, not in the attributes, that's why I cannot use a custom method.

Ideally, I would have something like:

```
belongs_to :addonable,  serializer: ContainerSerializer, polymorphic: true, as: :depot
```

But I cannot find anything similar. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For those who are using rails-api/active_model_serializers. It is possible to indicate :key. So in my case it would be   belongs_to :addonable,  serializer: DepotSerializer, polymorphic: true, key: :depot

Answer (score 0):

From `active_model_serializer` [document](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/active_model_serializers/0.8.1#label-Associations), it describes:

> You may also use the :serializer option to specify a custom serializer class and the :polymorphic option to specify an association that is polymorphic (STI), e.g.:
>
> has_many :comments, :serializer => CommentShortSerializer
>
> has_one :reviewer, :polymorphic => true
>
> **Serializers are only concerned with multiplicity, and not ownership**. belongs_to ActiveRecord associations can be included using has_one in your serializer.

So in your case, let use `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`:

```
has_one :addonable, serializer: DepotSerializer, polymorphic: true
```

Tested, it works in my project!

Comment: This still renders the same result as the not desired. The object is under the key :addonable.  I want it under the key :depot.

Comment: @dioshari: how about just defining a :depot attribute, it returns : addonable actually?

Comment: Sorry I got confused. I'm actually using rails-api/active_model_serializers. So the attributes are under another hash key than the associations. Looking into the right documentation I just saw that I can use :key to specify the name of the hash. Thank you for your time